# Return a Boolean if an element occurs three times in a row in an array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am trying to write a method that takes an array and returns `true`if there is an element that occurs three times in a row or `false` if it doesn't.  I can't think of the syntax. Would you use `count`? See the example below.

```
def got_three?(array)

end
```

`got_three?([1,2,2,3,4,4,4,5,6])` would return `true` as `4` shows up three times in a row.

Comment: Just loop through the array comparing each element with the one next to it, if they match increment a counter, if they don't zero it. If your counter gets to three exit and return true, if you get to the end of the array return false. Can't give you syntax as I've never used Ruby.

Comment: what if it appears more than 3 times?

Answer (score 3):

Toying with the new Ruby 2.3.0 method [chunk_while](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk_while):

```
def got_three?(array)
  array.chunk_while(&:==).any?{|g| g.size >= 3}
end
```

Comment: Wow, neat! This is very cool. Although maybe `g.size >= 3` to handle the case of four or more in a row (although admittedly OP didn't specify how those should be handled)

Comment: @SteveTurczyn Yes that is better.

Answer (score 3):

With [Enumerable#chunk](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk):

```
def got_three?(xs)
  xs.chunk(&:itself).any? { |y, ys| ys.size >= 3 }
end
```

Comment: I'd think this is pretty efficient considering that `chunk` is implemented in C and returns an enumerator. It also reads extremely well (no ugly indices!) and is usable for any number of consecutive values.

Answer (score 1):

Not so smart but a naive one (using `a` instead of `array` since it is long):

```
a.each_index.any?{|i| a[i] == a[i + 1] and a[i + 1] == a[i + 2]}
```

I assume you don't have any `nil` in the array.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn I assumed that is not the case, as it is usually not. I added an explicit conditioning.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative which may be more performant (as per @sawa's comments)...

```
def got_three?(array)
  (0..(array.count-2)).any?{|i|array[i] == array[1+1] && array[i] == array[i+2]}
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Look, ma, no indices!

```
def ducks_in_a_row?(arr, n)
  cnt = 0
  last = arr.first
  arr.each do |d|
    if d==last
      cnt += 1
      return true if cnt==n
    else
      last = d
      cnt = 1
    end
  end
  false
end

ducks_in_a_row?([1,2,3,4,5,6,6,7,7,7], 3)
  #=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def got_three?(array)
  array.each_cons(3).map{|g|g.uniq.length == 1}.any?
end
```

or as @wandmaker suggests...

```
def got_three?(array)
  array.each_cons(3).any?{|g|g.uniq.length == 1}
end
```

Comment: You could also use `array.each_cons(3).any?{|g|g.uniq.length == 1}`

Comment: Even with the improvement this is inefficient. Compare the work done for each triple as compared to `arr[i] == arr[i+1] && arr[i] == arr[i+2]`, considering that the second condition is not evaluated when the first is `true`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland yes, my other answer is better performance.  Your's is cool... kind of retro!  :)

Comment: Steve, I am, if nothing else, retro.

Comment: I had noticed you had two answers. I considered comparing this answer to  Steve's, but it didn't make the cut.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on this problem - I tried to make it generic, hopefully efficient so that the loop terminates as soon as n-consecutive elements are found.

```
def got_consecutive?(array, n = 3)
    case array.size
    when 0...n
        return false 
    when n
        return array.uniq.size == n
    else
        array[n..-1].each_with_object(array[0...n]) do |i, t|
            (t.uniq.size == 1 ? (break t) : (t << i).shift)
        end.uniq.size == 1
    end
end

p got_consecutive?([])
#=> false
p got_consecutive?([1,2])
#=> false
p got_consecutive?([1,2,2,3,2,3,3,3], 3)
#=> true
p got_consecutive?([1,2,2,3,2,3,3,3], 4)
#=> false
p got_consecutive?([1,2,2,3,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4], 5)
#=> true
```

The code takes care of border cases first such as when array did not have `n` elements in which case answer is obviously `false`, and another one being when the array had only `n` elements - in which case just a uniqueness check would suffice.

For cases where array size is greater than `n`, the code uses [`Enumerable#each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) with the initial object being an array of `n` elements from the `array` - this array is used also as temporary work area to track `n` consecutive elements and perform a check whether all those elements are same or not.